How to make a Dropdown button that has a tree structure
Is it possible to make something like this with DropdownButton (or any other Flutter widget)?

By "Tree Structure" I mean that certain values of the list of selection when clicked, do not get selected, but refresh the DropDownButton's values with their children ones.
I couldn't think of a way of achieving this using DropdownButton or DropdownButton2.
